# Why setting to nil after releasing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I came across this method:

```
-(void) someMethod {
    NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    // Do stuff with anArray ... 
    [anArray release];
    anArray = nil;
}
```

Is setting the array to nil necessary?
In this code by sending a release message to the array, it will causes the array to be deallocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it is a pointless waste of key strokes because the variable anArray goes out of scope immediately.

In other cases, where the variable stays in scope for a while after you release the object its pointing to, it is a good idea, because, if you accidentally dereference it, you will get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS which is easy to spot, and if you send a message to it, it will be ignored (except for returning nil / 0).

Comment: Correction: it will not be 'ignored', it will return nil.

Comment: @Wayne Hartman: Yes, i know, I was being lazy.  Answer corrected.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, setting it to `nil` will help your code not crash if you reference the `dealloc`ed object.  If you reference a `dealloc`ed you will get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error and your app will crash.  Since a `nil` object returns `nil` if a message is sent to it, your app will not crash.

In the example you provide, it is not necessary to `nil` it out, since it is contained in a method.  However, you do not want to `nil` out a variable if you expect to use it somewhere else in the code, since the value will then be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary.
It is just for safe reason (to not send a message to a zombie)
And you can test if your ivar is nil or not to realloc:

```
[ivar release];
ivar=nil;
...
if (ivar==nil) {
  ivar = [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
[ivar setValue:@"toto"];
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't set it to nil, you can not test for == nil (which you might want from time to time).

Comment: And it's required if you wish to use the Garbage Collector.

Comment: @Arafangion : With GC, you don't need to release

Comment: Benoit: Indeed, releasing it becomes a no-op, but you DO need to nil it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary but considered good behaviour to set dangling pointers to nil.